# cannot build: No rule to make target

Tags: netbeans, makefile, cygwin

I'm trying to transfer a working project from visual c to netbeans, which I just installed.
However, it's not building. Below is the message.

```
    "/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/sam/Documents/NetBeansProjects/timerDAC'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/timerdac.exe
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/sam/Documents/NetBeansProjects/timerDAC'



cygwin warning:
      MS-DOS style path detected: /cygdrive/D/timer DAC code/EOGTester/DaqInTesteing\(New\)Out.c
      Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/D/timer DAC code/EOGTester/DaqInTesteing/(New/)Out.c
      CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
      Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
        http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames


make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/cygdrive/D/timer DAC code/EOGTester/DaqInTesteing\(New\)Out.c', needed by 'build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/_ext/1013452424/DaqInTesteing_New_Out.o'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/sam/Documents/NetBeansProjects/timerDAC'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:60: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/sam/Documents/NetBeansProjects/timerDAC'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

I read that the

> No rule to make target

error is usually due to a spelling error. However, this is someone else's project I'm importing, and I have to clue how to find where the spelling error is?

Also, the cygwin warning is mystifying, where the "MS-DOS style path detected" and the "preferred POSIX equivalent" only differs by a "/" and a "\"?

Comment: Yes, MS-DOS uses backslashes in paths, which can cause problems in Make. The presence of *parentheses* in the path is also ominous, especially since the backslashes preceded them; it looks suspiciously like something that escaped from a regex. What's in `/cygdrive/D/timer DAC code/EOGTester/DaqInTesteing/`?

Comment: Hi Beta, there is no DaqInTesteing folder, however there is a .c file
http://i567.photobucket.com/albums/ss114/samio_130/cake/picfivee.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should never use pathnames that contain whitespace with make.  Make simply doesn't support this in any real way.  Rename your directory `timer DAC code` so it does not contain whitespace.

Second, the backslashes here are SUPPOSED to be escaping the parentheses, so ignore that warning.  Cygwin is assuming that you meant to use them as directory separators but you didn't.

I'm not that familiar with the Cygwin port of make, but I believe that the backslashes are not being interpreted correctly.  Personally if I were you I'd rename these files so they didn't contain any special characters at all, such as parenthesis.

If you can't do that, then you should switch to quoting to escape them, rather than backslashes.  So, change instances of `DaqInTesteing\(New\)Out.c` to `'DaqInTesteing(New)Out.c'` (using single quotes around the word instead of backslashes to quote the special characters).

I'm assuming that the odd spelling `DaqInTesteing`, rather than `DaqInTesting`, is intentional.

If these things don't help we'll need to see the part of the makefile which is responsible for building these targets.

Comment: Hi MadSci, Where would I have to >change instances of DaqInTesteing\(New\)Out.c to 'DaqInTesteing(New)Out.c'< ? In the makefile? The owner of the code said he just used generated makefiles, so I didn't touch the makefile either, there's nothing in it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/79pqg5ft9sfb058/Makefile

Comment: Sure.  Makefiles are all that make reads; nothing else is interesting to make.  Look at the bottom of your makefile again; it says: `include nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk` and `include nbproject/Makefile-variables.mk`.  So look in those files.  Probably the latter.

Comment: I checked in both of those, but none of them had "DaqInTesteing\\(New\\)Out.c". However, in Make-Release.mk there was, and I changed it. However, upon building, it said: some #include or #error directives failed and then Make-Release.mk was automatically modified back.

Comment: basically, All i did was use his .c and .h files and added some libraries... makefile was autogenerated

Comment: Hi Madsci, I got rid of the parenthesis from DaqInTesteing(New)Out.c, and that got rid of the cygwin warning! thanks.
now, to fix all the rest of the problems :(

Comment: It's possible to use bizarre filenames (at least on UNIX), other than whitespace-containing ones, but it requires a very sound knowledge of shell quoting rules to attempt it.  Also I'm unfamiliar with how, if at all, Cygwin might differ from UNIX in this respect.  Far, far simpler is to just avoid them.